# E: Unable to locate package <pkg name>

Tags: php

I am new to php and drupal.my problem is i tried to install php and related pkgs in terminal.I followed this command to install php5

**sudo apt-get install php5 php5-cli php5-common php5-devel php5-mbstring php5-gd php5-mysql php5-pdo php5-xmlrpc php5-xml php5-pear**

after i entered this command i saw the error like as below.

```
E: Unable to locate package php5-devel
E: Unable to locate package php5-mbstring
E: Unable to locate package php5-pdo
E: Unable to locate package php5-xml
E: Unable to locate package php5-pear
```

I tried many ways to get solution for this but i didn't got solution to this.After many hours i taken reinstall ubuntu after that again same error is shows me. Can any one help me from this headache error.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: @KyleDomingo Well as he states he reinstalled Ubuntu, I guess you could class that as a **bit of a hint**

Comment: Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:    trusty

Comment: This happens when you try to install the php-modules with apt-get?

Comment: `php5-devel` is actually `php5-dev`. `php5-mbstring` and `php5-xml` is in `libapache2-mod-php5` (http://serverfault.com/questions/455388/how-to-install-php-xml-and-php-mbstring-on-php-5-4-9-4). `php5-pear` should be `php-pear`. `php5-pdo` is included in the db extension you intend to use. e.g., for mysql: `php5-mysql`

Comment: Shouldn't this question really be on Server Fault instead of Stack Overflow? Not really a programming question, it's more of a system administration question.

Comment: i got the solution now.

Comment: @SankarN, which one?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing php5 with php like so `sudo apt-get install php-curl` or if you have php7.0 installed use this command `sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl`.

You can check your php version using command `php -v`.